# How to search backwards in zsh/bash BUT relative to directory

Tags: bash, zsh, plugins, history, command-history

Problem:

In the terminal, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to do a backward-search using the zsh/bash history, it searches all commands sorted by most recently used.

Problem is some commands are completely irrelevant to my current directory.

Is there a zsh/bash plugin or a way to configure the backward-search to take into account the timestamp AND the relative directory path in order to display relevant commands that I've previously typed in this directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://github.com/larkery/zsh-histdb, which records the start and stop times of each history item and the working directory where it took place, but its implementation of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> is rather shaky. You probably will have to roll your own.